# How to create a new array position an element at first position based on a condition?

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `data`, I need to create a **new array**, where element matching variable `toBeFirst` is the first one.

Please note I cannot touch the original array `data`

```
const toBeFirst = 'b'
const data = [{name: 'a'},{name: 'b'},{name: 'e'}, {name: 'x'}]

// final result
const data = [{name: 'b'},{name: 'a'},{name: 'e'}, {name: 'x'}
```

any idea how to do it using latest js? can be done using reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append the elements, and prepend if its that special element:

```
const result = data.reduce((arr, el) => el.name === toBeFirst ? [el].concat(arr) : arr.concat([el]), []);
```

But mutating the array is probably eaiser:

```
data.unshift(data.splice(data.findIndex(el => el.name === toBeFirst), 1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would've been nice if you supplied code of your trials. Anyway, you could use double filtering. To answer your second question: yes, you can use `reduce`, see the snippet.

```js
const toBeFirst = 'b'
const data = [{name: 'a'},{name: 'b'},{name: 'e'}, {name: 'x'}];
const dataFirstB = data.filter(v => v.name === toBeFirst)
  .concat(data.filter(v => v.name !== toBeFirst));
console.log(dataFirstB);
// using a reducer
const dataReduced = data.reduce( (a, v) => 
  v.name !== toBeFirst ? [...a, v] : a,
  data.filter(v => v.name === toBeFirst));
console.log(dataReduced);
```